# Analytic Continuation Algorithm

Tags: complex, series-expansion

I am trying to analytically continue the following sum starting from $z = 0$.

$\sum_{n = 0}^{m} z^n$

I want $z = 2$ to be within the defined region. I have the following code:

```
SumOrder = 20;
ExpOrder = 20;
f[z_] = Sum[z^n, {n, 0, SumOrder}];
zns = {};
RotOrder = 100;
For[i = 0, i <= RotOrder, i++, 
  AppendTo[zns, 1 + E^(I \[Pi] (1 - i/RotOrder))]];
explist = {Sum[z^n, {n, 0, SumOrder}]};
For[i = 1, i <= RotOrder, i++, 
 AppendTo[explist, 
  Normal[Series[explist[[i]], {z, zns[[i]], ExpOrder}]]]]
z = 2;
explist[[RotOrder - 1]] // N
Clear[z]
```

The output is 2047 which is obviously wrong for high $m$ since the sum will converge to $\frac{1}{1-z}$. I'm not sure what is going wrong however.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Do you have a reference for the underlying mathematics? I'm not familiar with the approach you are taking.

Comment: The idea is that you perform a Taylor series expansion of a function. The series will be convergent within a circle of radius = |z-z0|; where z0 is the location of the nearest pole. The function is then well defined within this circle. If you the move to another point within the circle, you can perfor a series expansion about this point by performing a taylor series of your previous series. The function will now be defined with in two circle, this has "analytically continued" the function.